# enable javascript on webbrowser control win ec 7

Tags: c#, javascript, compact-framework, windows-ce

this is my first post in here.
I searched all over the web for a solution to this problem, but i have not found nothing.
I only read that Webbrowser haven't much support for javascript in win ec7.

But my first question is:

-Why a web page with javascript works fine in IE in wec7 and doesn't work in a webbrowser on the same platform?

I enabled all script options from the control panel, but it still not works.

How can I make the page works in webbrowser as it works in ie?

Thanks in advance for the help or the tips.

bennaloz

Answer (score 0):

### Q.

> -Why a web page with javascript works fine in IE in wec7 and doesn't work in a webbrowser on the same platform?

### A.

The compact framework has a much smaller Operating System than full blown Windows, otherwise it would be too large to fit on the device.

To make the compact framework smaller, many features that Microsoft could not foresee a use for were left off.

When Windows CE and Windows Mobile were first introduced, not many people were trying to use these devices to look at online content. A web browser was included, but a lot of things in this web browser were also limited (for the same reasons). Therefore, some JavaScript may work while other JavaScript will not.

Nothing is guaranteed to work with JavaScript, though.